# Mapping a range of real numbers to a range of integer numbers.

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

I have a set of real numbers within the range [-1.0, 1.0], and I want to map them to set of integers in [-2, 2]. What is the simplest mathematical formula to achieve this?

Comment: $f(x)=2{}{}{}$?

Comment: Should the mapping have certain properties? If so, which ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a mapping $A \rightarrow B$ that is both total and surjective, you could use

$$f(x) = [2x]$$

where [ ] rounds to the nearest integer.

It is total because $f(x)$ is defined for all $x \in A$. It is surjective because for every $y \in B$ there exists an $x \in A$ such that $f(x) = y$.

Note that if surjectivity is not required, you could just use a constant function such as

$$f(x) = 0$$

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!